# How to use QGeoCoordinate in Qt C++ , especially the azimuthTo() and distanceTo() objects?

Tags: c++, qt

This is my code:
After specifying two different coordinates (geo and geo2), how can I know the distance between them using distanceTo()

```
//enter code here
QGeoCoordinate geo;
geo.setLatitude(90);
geo.setLongitude(90);
QGeoCoordinate geo2;
geo2.setLatitude(53.213456);
geo2.setLongitude(-9.182547);
```

edit:
I have read the documentation but still unable to figure out the right way.

Comment: What are you getting and what are you expecting? I don't see you calling 'distanceTo' anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried `geo.distanceTo(geo2)`? That should give you the distance in meters, according to documentation, dismissing changes in altitude and assuming a perfectly spherical Earth.

Comment: You're right it worked. I didn't know it was as simple as that since I saw the documentation and I wasn't able to know the meaning of all this:
qreal QGeoCoordinate::distanceTo(const QGeoCoordinate &other) const 
Can you please illustrate this to me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what you mean by 'illustrate', but I posted the completed code as answer. You know what member functions are and how to call them, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgeocoordinate.html#distanceTo), it is a simple call of taking one of the two QGeoCoordinate objects and pass the other object to its member function.

So your code becomes:

```
QGeoCoordinate geo;
geo.setLatitude(90);
geo.setLongitude(90);
QGeoCoordinate geo2;
geo2.setLatitude(53.213456);
geo2.setLongitude(-9.182547);
qreal distanceInMeters = geo.distanceTo(geo2);
```